# Can not find BLE device using 32feet.NET

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use VS 2017 in windows 7 to write a hci tool for searching the BLE device.
I use bluetooth CSR 4.0 dongle(the driver is installed and works well) and BlueSoleil.

But when after the  BLE device's advertising, the program can not find it. I have tried to use other app like lightblue for searching, the BLE device is findable.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth;
using InTheHand.Net;
using InTheHand.Net.Sockets;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace hcitool
{
partial class Program
{
    static bool infoRatherThanName;
    static BluetoothAddress _searchAddress;

    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please specify command.");
            return 2;
        }
        var cmd = args[0];
        switch (cmd)
        {
            case "name":
                infoRatherThanName = false;
                break;
            case "info":
                infoRatherThanName = true;
                break;
            //-
            case "dev":
                return ShowRadios();
            //case "auth":
            //    return CauseAuth(GETADDRESS());
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Command: '" + cmd + 
     "'");
        }
        if (args.Length < 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please specify device address.");
            return 2;
        }
        var addrS = args[1];
        _searchAddress = BluetoothAddress.Parse(addrS);
        //
        var dev = new BluetoothDeviceInfo(_searchAddress);
        bool isInRange = GetCanConnectTo(dev);
        if (isInRange)
        {
            PrintDevice(dev);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Can't see that device.");
        }
        //
        Console.WriteLine("simple");
        return Simple();
        //return Fancier();
    }
```

When I run the program using：“hcitool.exe name 123456654321(the BLE address)” , it shows:  can't see that device.

The return value of GetCanConnectTo() is false so it shows:  can't see that device.

I do not know how  I could connect to the ble device using my code.

Comment: Windows 7 doe snot support BLE in any way. To be able to work with BLE device on Win 7 you must use third party driver. There is only one with more or less known API: BlueSoleil. Or you can develop your own. There is also WinUSB bused custom driver as well but I do not remember the link.

Comment: I have installed and used BlueSoleil. Please see the 2rd line of my question.

Comment: What GetCanConnectTo() does?

Comment: Ok, I took a look on 32feet BLE implementation on Windows platform and found that it supports BLE only with Microsoft Bluetooth stack on Windows 8 and above (I can be wrong so let someone who knows 32feet better correct me). So you have to use BlueSoleil BLE API directly or use other Bluetooth Library that supports BLE with BlueSoleil.